# Thread wont stop

Tags: java, multithreading, jframe

I have a program that runs a thread, when I click the exit button (a custom one) I tell the thread to stop, then dispose of the JFrame. But the thread keeps running; cranking my CPU to 100%;
Everytime I click a button, the clock opens. This is the code that opens it.

```
new ClockGui().main();
```

The ClockGui is the clock, and it is a separate .java file within my package which includes a separate main .java file.

In an addition, if it helps at all, I've noticed that every time I click the button my CPU goes up by 50%, and when I close the JFrame, the ClockGui that is, my CPU goes down by 25%. That's still an increase of 25%. So I'm guessing the problem is in the main .java file; maybe how I'm calling the ClockGui?

```
public boolean running = true;
...
private void exitButtonMouseClicked(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) { //this is the event that happens when I click the exit button                                     
        running = false;
        this.dispose(); //this closes the JFrame
}
public class myThread extends Thread {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            while(running) {
                ...
            }
        }
    }
```

The JFrame closes as expected, but my CPU is still at 100%. Am I closing the thread correctly? How do I fix my problem? I want the thread to stop.

Comment: Show us lines that keep rotating in your debugger session. Alternatively take stack snapshot with the jstack and provide code of three deepest methods.

Answer (score 7):

non-`volatile` variables are not guaranteed to propagate to other threads(immediately, in a timely manner, or at all), especially when HotSpot optimization occurs. Likely, `running = false` is seen as a dead-store and ignored.

You should declare `running` as:

```
public volatile boolean running = true;
```

Comment: Still spikes my CPU after I close the JFrame? any ideas?

Comment: @Arc Then there's logic you're not showing us that may be the issue